# Automating PTO Updates in Staff Timesheets with VBA - error updating correct cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a VBA project to update staff's Paid Time Off (PTO) in their timesheets. The PTO information provided includes only the start date and the number of hours used, without a specific date range. The code I'm using aims to locate the corresponding month tab in the timesheet based on the start date. If the PTO hours are less than or equal to 8, only the cell corresponding to the start date in the relevant month tab is updated. However, if the hours exceed 8, the cells to the right of the start date cell are continuously updated until the remaining hours are less than or equal to 8.

The code is supposed to skip updating cells in columns representing weekends since staff members only work from Monday to Friday. However, it seems that the current IsExcludedColumn function does not exclude these weekend columns from being updated. Additionally, if the cell is updated at the end of the week and there are hours remaining, it does not correctly add the remaining hours to the next month's time sheet.

Does anyone have any thoughts or ideas on how to resolve these issues?

[image: Timesheet screenshot]

[image: PTO list screenshot]

```
Sub UpdateTimesheets()
' Set the folder path to the directory containing the Excel files
Const folderPath As String = "C:\Users\smmy\Downloads\Test Copies 2\"

' Disable screen updating to improve performance
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Get the file name of the first Excel file in the folder
Dim fileName As String
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

' Loop through all Excel files in the folder
Do While fileName <> ""
    ' Check if the file is not a temporary file
    If Left(fileName, 7) <> "~$temp." Then
        ' Open the Excel file
        Dim timesheetWorkbook As Workbook
        Set timesheetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileName)

        ' Loop through the month tabs in the workbook
        Dim timesheetSheet As Worksheet
        For Each timesheetSheet In timesheetWorkbook.Sheets
            Select Case timesheetSheet.Name
                Case "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                    ' Find the corresponding PTO worksheet
                    Dim ptoSheet As Worksheet
                    Set ptoSheet = timesheetWorkbook.Sheets("FY12 PTO")

                    ' Loop through the PTO data in the PTO worksheet
                    Dim ptoRow As Long
                    For ptoRow = 2 To ptoSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                        ' Get the PTO type, start date, and hours from the PTO worksheet
                        Dim ptoType As String
                        Dim ptoStartDate As Date
                        Dim ptoHours As Double
                        ptoType = ptoSheet.Cells(ptoRow, 2).Value
                        ptoStartDate = DateValue(ptoSheet.Cells(ptoRow, 5).Value)
                        ptoHours = ptoSheet.Cells(ptoRow, 7).Value

                        ' Find the month tab corresponding to the PTO start date
                        Dim monthTab As Worksheet
                        Set monthTab = timesheetWorkbook.Sheets(Format(ptoStartDate, "mmmm"))

                        If Not monthTab Is Nothing Then
                            ' Find the corresponding date column in the month tab
                            Dim dateColumn As Range
                            Set dateColumn = monthTab.Range("C10:AK10").Find(What:=Day(ptoStartDate), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

                            If Not dateColumn Is Nothing Then
                                ' Find the row for the PTO type in the month tab
                                Dim ptoTypeRow As Range
                                Set ptoTypeRow = monthTab.Range("A13:A17").Find(What:=ptoType, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

                                If Not ptoTypeRow Is Nothing Then
                                    ' Get the cell in the timesheet for updating hours
                                    Dim currentCell As Range
                                    Set currentCell = monthTab.Cells(ptoTypeRow.Row, dateColumn.Column)

                                    ' Skip if the cell is in one of the excluded columns or has a holiday value
                                    If Not IsExcludedColumn(currentCell) And monthTab.Cells(15, currentCell.Column).Value <> "Holiday" Then
                                        ' Add hours to the timesheet cells
                                        Do While ptoHours > 0
                                            Dim remainingHours As Double
                                            remainingHours = WorksheetFunction.Max(8 - currentCell.Value, 0)

                                            If remainingHours > 0 Then
                                                If ptoHours >= remainingHours Then
                                                    currentCell.Value = currentCell.Value + remainingHours
                                                    ptoHours = ptoHours - remainingHours
                                                Else
                                                    currentCell.Value = currentCell.Value + ptoHours
                                                    ptoHours = 0
                                                End If
                                            End If

                                            If currentCell.Column = Columns("AL").Column Then
                                                Exit Do  ' Exit loop if column AL is reached
                                            End If

                                            Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 1)
                                        Loop
                                    End If
                                Else
                                    MsgBox "Row not found for PTO type '" & ptoType & "' in sheet '" & monthTab.Name & "'", vbExclamation
                                End If
                            Else
                                MsgBox "Column not found for date " & Format(ptoStartDate, "d") & " in sheet '" & monthTab.Name & "'", vbExclamation
                            End If
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Month tab not found for date " & Format(ptoStartDate, "mmmm"), vbExclamation
                        End If
                    Next ptoRow
            End Select
        Next timesheetSheet

        ' Save and close the Excel file
        timesheetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If

    ' Get the file name of the next Excel file in the folder
    fileName = Dir
Loop

' Enable screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Timesheets have been updated.", vbInformation
```

End Sub

```
Function IsExcludedColumn(cell As Range) As Boolean
Dim excludedColumns As Variant
excludedColumns = Array("C", "D", "J", "K", "Q", "R", "X", "Y", "AE", "AF", "AL")

Dim columnLetter As String
columnLetter = Split(cell.Address, "$")(1)

If columnLetter > "AL" Then
    IsExcludedColumn = True
Else
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(excludedColumns) To UBound(excludedColumns)
        If columnLetter = excludedColumns(i) Then
            IsExcludedColumn = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End If

IsExcludedColumn = False
```

End Function

Comment: Looking to the pictures you show, I must confess I do not understand what you try accomplishing. Not understanding that, looking to a not working code looks something useless, sorry. Anyhow, your function looks strange for me. What do you expect from `If columnLetter > "AL"`?

Comment: Which is the input for the task you try accomplishing? A **total number of hours** and a **starting date** and you try splitting them in sheet as your first picture shows, only skipping the weekends? Then, how the columns letters you want excluding are all the same, independent of the month peculiarity? Do you take care that the weekends to be all the time in the same position and you start the month in an apropriate place to keep this arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

If the used function is your problem, please use the next (more compact) one, not needing any iteration:

```
Function IsExcludedColumn(cell As Range) As Boolean
  Const exclCols As String = "C:D,J:K,Q:R,X:Y,AE:AF,AL:AL"
  If Not Intersect(cell.Parent.Range(exclCols).EntireColumn, cell) Is Nothing Then IsExcludedColumn= True
End Function
```